# MsDeploy with DbDacFx provider and Database reference

Tags: database, reference, msdeploy, dacpac

We are using DbDacFx provider to sync our production machine.
We have ssdt database project in our solution that we deploy along with our website.
The A.sqlproj has references to master.dacpac and another database project's dacpac, say X.dacpac.

All dacpacs are in same location for deployment.

When we try to deploy the A.dacpac we get errors as below:

*Info: Deploying package to database: Faulted. Error: The reference to external elements from the source named 'X.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded. Error: The reference to external elements from the source named 'master.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded. .....above errors repeated multiple times..... An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Member 'ClassName' was not found.    at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement(String name, Type& foundType)    at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetString(String name)  at System.Exception..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Base64EncodingHelper.DeserializeHelper(BinaryFormatter formatter, Byte[] buffer)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Base64EncodingHelper.Deserialize(String str, Exception& handledException)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SerializationHelper.Deserialize(String str)   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.ProcessExeOutput()    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.RunExecutableAsync(String exeName, String arguments, Int32 waitInterval, Int32 retryAttempts)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId) Error: Member 'ClassName' was not found. at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement(String name, Type& foundType)    at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetString(String name)  at System.Exception..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) Error count: 1.*

Need to know how we can overcome the issues.
Thanks
Yatin.

Comment: Additionally, here are some warnings given
Warning: No file was supplied for reference X.dacpac; deployment might fail. When package was created, the original referenced file was located C:\BUILDS\9\DEV\.....\SHAREDASSEMBLIES\X.DACPAC.
Warning: No file was supplied for reference master.dacpac; deployment might fail. When package was created, the original referenced file was located C:\BUILDS\9\DEV\...\SHAREDASSEMBLIES\MASTER.DACPAC.

These warnings are issued by MsDeploy while using package provider and manifest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still a pain.
We plan on scripting the sqlpackage.exe file command through runCommand provider and get automation going !!
Closing the question.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do the referenced dacpacs exist on the machine that is running the deploy?

If they do the easiest is to copy the dacpacs into the same folder as the dacpac you are deploying as the same directory will be checked, failing that the original path that contained the original dacpac.

Comment: Yes, all the dacpac do exists together in same folder.
But event then, when during deployment seems, the dacpac reference is looking for the dacpacs from shared folder where from they were built !!

Comment: The original path is stored in the dacpac but the local folder should be used if it is not found, have you got an odd working directory?

Comment: Here is over all process:
1> we build the deployment package using a manifest file as source and package provider as destination. The package has the dacpac and website contents.
2> deploy the package to the servers using remote MS deploy agent
3> we are able to deploy the dacpac if we use the SqlPackage.exe file, and all packages being in same folder.
4> In the manifest file, we are using the dbDacFx provider to add the main database dacpac to package.
5> the referenced dacpacs are added with filePath provider.